# Why this process is executed when the simulation starts

Tags: vhdl, fpga, hdl, modelsim, asic

This is a simple entity just to know the usage of "process"

My question is:
Why the process is executed when the simulation just starts? I think the process wakes up when the signals in the sensitivity list change, but in this example, the assignment to signal 'a' is 3ns after the simulation starts.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;  
use ieee.numeric_std.all;         
use ieee.math_real.all;           

entity test4 is
    port (
        a : in bit;
        f : out bit
    );

end test4;

architecture test4_arc of test4 is
    signal b : bit;
begin

    process(a)
    begin
        report "process triggered";
        
        b <= a;
        f <= not a;
    end process;

end test4_arc;
```

Here is the testbench

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use std.textio.all;
use ieee.std_logic_textio.all;
-----------------------------------------------------------
entity test4tb is
end entity ;
-----------------------------------------------------------
architecture testbench of test4tb  is

   component test4
    port (
        a : in bit;
        f : out bit
    );
   end component;

signal atest,ftest : bit;

begin
    -----------------------------------------------------------
    process
    begin
        wait for 3ns;
        atest <= '0';
        wait for 5ns;
        atest <= '1';
        wait for 5ns;
    end process ;

    dut : test4 port map (
        a => atest,
        f => ftest
    );

end architecture testbench;
```

message from console of Modelsim

```
# ** Note: process triggered
#    Time: 0 ns  Iteration: 0  Instance: /test4tb/dut
# ** Note: process triggered
#    Time: 8 ns  Iteration: 1  Instance: /test4tb/dut
# ** Note: process triggered
#    Time: 16 ns  Iteration: 1  Instance: /test4tb/dut
# ** Note: process triggered
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All processes will execute at least once at time 0. A `process` with a sensitivity list is assumed to have a `wait on <list>` as the last statement in the process.
You can read this in **VHDL LRM Section 11.3 Process Statement**:

*If a process sensitivity list appears following the reserved word process, then the process statement is
assumed to contain an implicit wait statement as the last statement of the process statement part; this implicit wait statement is of the form*

```vhdl
wait on sensitivity_list;
```

And further in LRM section **14.7.5.2 Initialization**:

*f) For each nonpostponed process P in the model, the following actions occur in the indicated order: 1) The process executes until it suspends.*

So all processes will run until they first suspend in the first delta cycle of the simulation. Because processes are actually infinite loops, they have to start somewhere.